# Letsencrypt is no longer an option for websites that need to support outdated systems, right?

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have a few questions about this issue:

**Question 1.** So the first root certificate from lets-encrypt has expired on September 30/2021. If I want my website to support lots of users in outdated systems, letsencrypt is no longer an option, right?

**Question 2.** What would be a viable provider to support lots of users in outdated systems like Windows 7, XP, etc...?

**Question 3.** What are relevant websites with letsencrypt certificates doing about this in order to support outdated clients?

**Question 4.** I have been unable to find any specific information on what to do about those expiring root certificates in order to keep support for outdated clients... The only thing I can think of is to change to a certificate provider whose original root certificates are not expired yet, is that the only option?

Comment: Windows >= XP SP3 [works](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificate-compatibility/)

Comment: It seem's they arrive to resolve it here : https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/users-of-older-android-and-windows-7-not-able-to-access-website/161557/15

Answer (score 0):

First question: depends on which systems do you want to support? there is [Let's Encrypt compatibilty page for reference](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificate-compatibility/) to look. As far is see most thing will work but certificate expiring and Android >= 2.3.6 will need its [certificate chain managed](https://letsencrypt.org/2020/12/21/extending-android-compatibility.html). To sum up, it depend but most systems will work

Second question: To Windows 7,XP if their latest are applied they should work assuming [left enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd349801(v=ws.10)).

Third question : They probably setting up certificate chains up to send diffirent chains depending on which device their on like on android >=2.3.6 and up to 7.1.1 should get the right chain if acme client configured and up to date

Fourth question : they can add ISRG Root X1 certificate to their devices